# Процессы php-fpm не умирают

Tags: apache, centos, vps, php-fpm

Есть сервер CentOS 7 apache с mpm event, который работает c php-fpm.

Для чистоты эксперимента поднял его копию на виртуальной машине.

Суть в следующем - при большом количестве обращений плодится большое количество процессов php-fpm, которые затем не умирают, хотя должны.

вот настройки из www.conf:

```
    pm = dynamic

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 50

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 2

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.min_spare_servers = 1

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.max_spare_servers = 2

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 12s

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 500
```

А результат работы на локальной машине через 10 минут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все процессы находятся в состоянии reading headers.
Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению ответа на этот вопрос не удалось получить нигде в интернете.

Однако, все дело в настройках apache.
файл php.conf у меня был таким:

```
<Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">

    ProxySet disablereuse=off
</Proxy>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Однако нужно было сделать его таким:

```
<Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">

    ProxySet disablereuse=on connectiontimeout=3 timeout=60
</Proxy>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Все дело в параметре **ProxySet disablereuse=on**
Если он отключен - апач не закрывает созданные процессы и php-fpm оказывается не в состоянии их контролировать...